# How do I easily copy a filename and a line like "filename:line" in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, copy-paste, shortcut

Does there a shortcut for copying the current cursor position's filename and line number in a "**filename:line**" format?
For pasting it in a QuickOpen menu, you know.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new context menu item "Copy File and Line" appears in the latest Xcode update.
Also, it has a default shortcut ⌃⌥⌘C
It wasn't in an Xcode a year before.